# how to make yahoo like newsfeed that is on yahoo's front page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, dhtml, jsf-2.2

I'm tying to make identical or very similar to yahoo newsfeed that is present on it's front page. I have put the image below

[image: this is what I actually like to do with jQuery]

my website is java based, Spring and Jsf 2.0 and primefaces.

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: I look around the internet and look to reverse engineer it without success, but I'm thinking there is already made plugin like this one and I'm hoping someone to point that out to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has exactly what I was looking for.

http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_2.htm